# img not showing in Django static

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, pycharm

I use Django 2.0.3 and I want try static , I create one in app folder and my code like this.

```
{% load static %}
```

And for pic is :

```
<img src="{% static 'images/ic_team.png' %}">
```

in setting the dir of static is :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

but the pic comes like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSTEc.png)

Answer (score 0):

you have to actually route /static to serve your static files ...

normally you would do this in production using apache or nginx or simillar

if you are running with `debug=True` in your settings you can use django static file finders (something like the below)

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]
STATICFILES_DIRS = [        os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"..","usr","local","www","documents","media")),
]
```

but be aware it wont work unless debug is set to true, and this is never recommended for production servers

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your static folder is inside the app folder in your case will be something like:

```
your_app_name/static/images/ic_team.png
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 0):

You have this in the settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

put your static files in the project root folder